# Jquery loop all radio boxes and return value

Tags: jquery

how would i loop through all the radio boxes on the page and get the value?
have the following command got anything to do with it?

```
$('input[type=radio]')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update:

To loop through checked ones, you can use the `:checked` filter selector this way:

```
$(':radio:checked').each(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

---

You can use the [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method like this with `:radio` (shortcut) filter selector:

```
$(':radio').each(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
});
```